# 5 Day Forecast using Nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I have set up a program that gets my weather for 1 day fine, but I have no idea how to get the other 4 days information because on the xml file the days all have the same name. How do I access the information from the different days?

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2473224 The Xml i am using

Code:

```
string query = String.Format("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2473224");
XmlDocument wData = new XmlDocument();
wData.Load(query);

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(wData.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("yweather", "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");

XmlNode channel = wData.SelectSingleNode("rss").SelectSingleNode("channel");
XmlNodeList nodes = wData.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item/yweather:forecast", manager);

string temperature = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["temp"].Value;

string condition = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:condition", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;

string humidity = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:atmosphere", manager).Attributes["humidity"].Value;

string WindSpeed = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:wind", manager).Attributes["speed"].Value;

string town = channel.SelectSingleNode("yweather:location", manager).Attributes["city"].Value;

string tfcond = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["text"].Value;

string tfhigh = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["high"].Value;

string tflow = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectSingleNode("yweather:forecast", manager).Attributes["low"].Value;
```

Well I figured it out by assigning the values to an array like this and using some of the code like this.

var fiveDays = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectNodes("yweather:forecast", manager);
            foreach (XmlNode node in fiveDays)
            {
                var day = node.Attributes["day"].Value;
                dayarray[i] = (day);
                //
                var text = node.Attributes["text"].Value;
                textarray[i] = (text);
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the XmlNode.SelectNodes method instead of SelectSingleNode.

This will return a list that you can then iterate through and copy the values to where you need them.

```
var fiveDays = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectNodes("yweather:forecast", manager);
foreach (XmlNode node in fiveDays)
{
    var text = node.Attributes["text"].Value;
    var high = node.Attributes["high"].Value;
    var low = node.Attributes["low"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a collection of the upcoming days, you can then loop over them to get the details on each day:

```
var upcomingDays = channel.SelectSingleNode("item").SelectNodes("yweather:forecast", manager);

foreach(XmlNode d in upcomingDays)
{
    //d.Attributes["day"].Value;
}
```

I ran this in LINQPad and it worked fine.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the xpath `wData.SelectNodes("channel/item//yweather:forcast", manager)` to return an XmlNodeList.

Comment: @LeeHiles yes, but I figured I'd keep with the way the OP had things structured

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you use a deserializer like [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and classes. With the following classes:

```
[XmlRoot("rss")]
public class RssRoot
{
    [XmlElement("channel")]
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }
}
public class Channel
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    // add other properties, if relevant
}
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("forecast", Namespace="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0")]
    public List<Forecast> Forecasts { get; set; }
    // add other properties, if relevant
}
public class Forecast
{
    [XmlAttribute("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    // add other attributes, if relevant
}
```

This will get your data from the URL in `query`

```
string query = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2473224";
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(query))
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RssRoot));
    var rss = (RssRoot)ser.Deserialize(reader);
    // use rss
}
```

If you want to continue to work with the XML using `XmlDocument`, you should use [`SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get multiple `forecast` nodes, instead of getting a single node.